# Localization in WPF

Tags: wpf, localization, resx

I am starting a new application in WPF and I am curious how to handle Localization? In WinForms you can use resx strings for the UI text, how is this done in WPF? Is there a special binding syntax for binding to resx resources or is there a different way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a MarkupExtension.
https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html
With this tutorial you can implement it yourself.

Or you can use a nuget package.