# Update resource string (Text in GUI) after culture change in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, internationalization

I am working on Localization of WPF application. My question is While i change a language from Combo Box (Drop down), I want to update text of whole application. But i don't know how to do it.

I am using .resx file as my resource file.

E.g. if selected language is English then text will be in english but when i change it to french, I want to update text of buttons from french resource file.

Suggession of good article is also acceptable. I am looking for good solution for big application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to be able to keep already open Views (with unsaved data, etc.) and just dynamically translate them? Or is it ok that you close all open windows first and semi-restart the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localization in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795025/localization-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

from all solution i saw, the best is to use dictionnary with string, binding to dynamic resources, and a string manager

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using Trace.Lib;

namespace Atlas.SSUP.Client.Core.Components.Managers
{
    public class StringManager
    {
        public static readonly StringManager Instance = new StringManager();

        /// <summary>
        /// Private constructor for singleton pattern
        /// </summary>
        private StringManager()
        {
        }

        private readonly CultureInfo DefaultCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

        private ResourceDictionary LanguageDictionary { get; set; }

        private Collection<ResourceDictionary> Root
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].MergedDictionaries; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a string from the common resource file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.of the desired string.</param>
        /// <returns>The string corresponding to the key provided.</returns>
        public string GetString(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                string value = LanguageDictionary[key] as string;
                if (value == null || value.Contains("String.Empty"))
                    value = string.Empty;

                return value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                BusinessLogger.Manage(e);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public void SetCulture( string newSource )
        {
            try
            {
                ResourceDictionary langOld = Root.Single(p => p.Source.OriginalString.Contains("Strings."));
                if (langOld != null)
                {
                    ResourceDictionary lang = LoadDictionary(newSource);
                    if (lang != null)
                    {

                        Application.Current.Resources.BeginInit();

                        Root.Remove(langOld);
                        Root.Insert(0,lang);

                        Application.Current.Resources.EndInit();

                        LanguageDictionary = lang;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                BusinessLogger.Manage(e);
                throw;
            }
        }


        public void Load()
        {
            Collection<ResourceDictionary> toRemove = new Collection<ResourceDictionary>();
            Collection<ResourceDictionary> toAdd = new Collection<ResourceDictionary>();

            foreach (ResourceDictionary res in Root)
            {
                if (res.Source.OriginalString.Contains("/Atlas.SSUP.Client.Core;Component/Resources/"))
                {
                    ResourceDictionary newDico = LoadDictionary(res.Source.OriginalString.Replace("/Atlas.SSUP.Client.Core;Component/Resources/", ""));
                    if (newDico != null)
                    {
                        toAdd.Add(newDico);
                        toRemove.Add(res);
                    }
                }
            }

            Application.Current.Resources.BeginInit();

            foreach (ResourceDictionary res in toRemove)
                Root.Remove(res);
            foreach (ResourceDictionary res in toAdd)
                Root.Add(res);

            Application.Current.Resources.EndInit();
        }

        private ResourceDictionary LoadDictionary(string source)
        {
            Stream streamInfo = null;
            ResourceDictionary dictionary = null;

            try
            {
                streamInfo = DistantManager.Instance.GetResource(source);

                if (streamInfo != null)
                {
                    Uri baseUri = DistantManager.Instance.GetUri(source);

                    dictionary = XamlReader.Load(streamInfo) as ResourceDictionary;

                    dictionary.Source = baseUri;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                BusinessLogger.Manage(e);
                return null;
            }

            return dictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:w="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore">

<!-- Font size on map station labels -->
<s:Double x:Key="StationFontSize">12</s:Double>

<!-- FlowDirection LeftToRight ou RightToLeft -->
<w:FlowDirection x:Key="FlowDirection">LeftToRight</w:FlowDirection>

<!-- Dialog -->
<s:String x:Key="String.Dialog.OK">OK</s:String>
<s:String x:Key="String.Dialog.Cancel">Cancel</s:String>
<s:String x:Key="String.Dialog.Yes">Yes</s:String>
<s:String x:Key="String.Dialog.No">No</s:String>
```

or you have another solution here but much more complex [cbr](http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl)