# Changing the text field of a button on creation in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I have an application which has support for multiple different languages and as such one of the requirements is that the user experience should not change regardless of language. I'm currently have a dialog box which has multiple buttons in English but is there a way to dynamically change the text fields of the buttons?

Comment: What you're really asking is "how do I localize an application".

WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795025/localization-in-wpf  
Store: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a MarkupExtension that does all the heavy work:

```
public class TranlationExtension : MarkupExtension
{
   public string Key { get; set; }

    public TranlationExtension(string key)
    {
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding("TranslationDictionary[" + Key + "]");
        binding.Source = MyTranslations;

        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

The MyTranslations must be a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged if the Culture Changes.

Useage:

```
<Button Content="{local:Tranlation TheKeyOfTheTranslationThatIsUsedInTheDictionaryAswell }"/>
```

The Approach is described here http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

Answer (score -1):

You can bind `content` property of the `button` to property in your viewmodel, for example:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonTxt}"/>
```

Then you can set `ButtonTxt` property in viewmodel regardles of selected language e.g.

```
if (languageId == Languages.English) {
   ButtonTxt = buttonTextInEnglish;
}
```